# Bouncing/reflecting my player off walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I'm recreating a movement system from dragon quest heroes rocket slime on the DS. In that game, the player can hold down the A button and stretch their slime main character in a direction. Letting go of A while it's stretched would sling them off in that direction.

Here's a gif of what it looks like:

[image: The bouncy movement I'm looking for]

Notice how he bounces off the walls diagonally. My replication currently looks like this (ignore the buggy animations :P)

[image]

It looks good! However, if I were to hit a wall diagonally, I would just move backwards in the opposite direction rather than reflecting off it.

Here's the code for how I handle bouncing off walls.

```
IEnumerator wallBounce(Vector2 hitVelocity)
{
    playerAnimator.enabled = true;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
    playerAnimator.CrossFade("Walking " + curDirection, 0); // place holder animation
    pVelocity = Vector2.Scale(-pVelocity,new Vector2(0.25f,0.25f));
    endPos = transform.position + new Vector3(pVelocity.x, pVelocity.y);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    curState = state.blasting;

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, endPos, 5f * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

I know about the Vector3.Reflect method in Unity but I'm not really sure how to implement it into my current code.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have done it.

I get the reflection vector like this:

```
Vector3 reflectedVelocity = Vector3.Reflect(pVelocity*.5f, foundHit.normal);
```

And then pass it to wallBounce as the hitVelocity.
                StartCoroutine(wallBounce(reflectedVelocity));

I then changed this line:

```
endPos = transform.position + new Vector3(pVelocity.x, pVelocity.y);
```

into

```
endPos = transform.position + hitVelocity;
```